# I ran 'gem update' by accident can i revert it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I ran 'gem update' to try to fix a problem in a different app i was working on. Now my main app doesn't work properly because i have a bunch of too-new gems. Is there a way to undo the gem update? Or revert my gems to the versions mentioned in my team's Gemfile.lock file?

Update: It specifically complains about Rake when i try to run 'rake spec'
(Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.5.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.)

Comment: Are you using git? Or some other version control?

Comment: yes, i am using git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you currently have a more recent version of a gem than is specified in your Gemfile.lock, then it should suffice to rewrite the Gemfile with the versions mentioned in Gemfile.lock and run a `bundle install`.

I tested this locally (downgraded a version in both Gemfile.lock and Gemfile) and bundler installed the old version without problems.

Comment: Use `git checkout -- Gemfile.lock` to revert to your old `Gemfile.lock` if you've accidentally updated it too.

Comment: I still get the same error. It complains about Rake specifically "Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.5.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this."

Comment: Try using `bundle clean` to clean out the version not specified in your gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

Run 'gem uninstall rake' if you have multiple versions it will ask you which you wish to remove.

Then run 'gem install rake -v 10.4.2' to install the right version.

Worked for me and much less risky than bundle updating everything.